# Каскадное удаление с БД one-to-many Hibernete

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

Имею две таблицы DEPARTMENT и EMPLOYEE (первая родительская, а вторая - дочерняя). То есть, каждому департаменту соответствует список сотрудников (связь one-to-many). Сотрудники не могут существовать вне департамента, но может существовать департамент без сотрудников. По-этому,  мне нужно чтобы при удалении департамента из таблицы DEPARTMENT удалялись соответствующие ему сотрудники с таблицы EMPLOYEE.

Реализовать это нужно с помощью Hibernate. Перепробовал уйму разных вариантов, но при выполнении операции получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`STAFF`.`EMPLOYEE`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ons3ycsifhocods0wpg7gym58` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `DEPARTMENT` (`id`))
```

Вот исходники:

DepartmentEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class DepartmentDataSet implements Serializable  {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name", unique = false, updatable = true, length = 45)
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Set<EmployeeDataSet> employeesSet;

public DepartmentDataSet() {
}

public DepartmentDataSet(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<EmployeeDataSet> getEmployeesSet() {
    return employeesSet;
}

public void setEmployeesSet(Set<EmployeeDataSet> employeesSet) {
    this.employeesSet = employeesSet;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UserDataSet{" + "id=" + id + "', name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
}
}
```

EmployeeEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeDataSet  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "department_id", unique = false, updatable = true)
    private int departmentId;

     @Column(name = "age", unique = false, updatable = true)
    private String age;

    @Column(name = "type", unique = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = false, updatable = true, length = 25)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "language", unique = false, updatable = true, length = 25)
    private String language;

    @Column(name = "methodology", unique = false, updatable = true, length = 25)
    private String methodology;

    public EmployeeDataSet() {
    }

    public EmployeeDataSet(String name, String type, String age, int department_id, String methodology,
                           String language) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setType(type);
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setDepartmentId(department_id);
        this.setMethodology(methodology);
        this.setLanguage(language);
    }

    public EmployeeDataSet(int id, String name, String type, String age, int department_id, String methodology,
                           String language) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName(name);
        this.setType(type);
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setDepartmentId(department_id);
        this.setMethodology(methodology);
        this.setLanguage(language);
    }


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

public String getMethodology() {
    return methodology;
}

public void setMethodology(String methodology) {
    this.methodology = methodology;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UserDataSet{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + "', age='" + age +
            ", type='" + departmentId + '\'' +  '}';
}
}
```

DepartmentDAO:

```
   public void removeDepartment(String name) throws HibernateException {
  session.beginTransaction();
  String hql = "delete from DepartmentDataSet where name = :name";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  query.setString("name", name);
  int rowCount = query.executeUpdate();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  System.out.println(">>DepartmentDDAO removeDepartment: " + rowCount);
}
```

Если сделать метод removeDepartment так, как показано ниже, то почему-то все работает. Но мне нужно чтобы мой метод получал имя департамента, а не его id.

```
 public void removeDepartment(int id) throws HibernateException {
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(session.get(DepartmentDataSet.class, 3));
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Буду рад любым подсказкам куда копать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аннотация `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` срабатывает только при удалении конкретной записи методом `session.delete`. У Вас другой случай - идёт удаление результатов SQL-выборки: метод `delete` не вызывается, а в `executeUpdate` отрабатывает "чистый" `SQL` и функции СУБД. `JPA` в этом процессе уже не участвует и никакие аннотации не уходят в СУБД вместе с `SQL`-запросом.

Решить задачу можно двумя способами.

1. Осуществить сначала выборку списка сущностей по имени, а затем пройти по списку и для каждой сущности вызвать `session.delete`.
2. Оставить запрос как есть, но указать на уровне СУБД каскадное удаление дочерних записей. Для этого, при создании `FOREIGN KEY` следует добавить `ON DELETE CASCADE`.